# How to create one function on onLoad and onBeforeUnload event

Tags: javascript, onload, onbeforeunload

I have the following code to call the onLoad and onBeforeUnload event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var startime = (new Date()).getTime();
window.onload = record_visit_ol; //ol - onload
window.onbeforeunload = record_visit_obul; //obul = onbeforeunload

function record_visit_ol() {
    var x = (window.ActiveXObject) ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open("GET", "count_visit.php?t=" + (((new Date()).getTime() - startime) / 1000)+"&type=ol&url="+escape(window.location.href), false);
    x.send(null);
}

function record_visit_obul() {
    var x = (window.ActiveXObject) ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open("GET", "count_visit.php?t=" + (((new Date()).getTime() - startime) / 1000)+"&type=obul&url="+escape(window.location.href), false);
    x.send(null);
}
```

That works great. However, I have 2 function for 2 events. I have tried creating 1 function only but it fires both events during onLoad.

Here's the code that fires even the onBeforeUnload event on loading a page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var startime = (new Date()).getTime();
window.onload = record_visit('ol'); //ol - onload
window.onbeforeunload = record_visit('obul'); //obul = onbeforeunload

function record_visit(value) {
    var x = (window.ActiveXObject) ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open("GET", "count_visit.php?t=" + (((new Date()).getTime() - startime) / 1000)+"&type="+value+"&url="+escape(window.location.href), false);
    x.send(null);
}
```

Comment: When you have it working make sure you check this across different browsers. If I remember correctly: not all browsers will let you make ajax calls in `onbeforeunload`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the function in the 2nd set of code.  You need to pass a function:

```
window.onload = function(){
    record_visit('ol'); //ol - onload
}

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    record_visit('obul'); //obul = onbeforeunload
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
window.onload = function(){ record_visit('ol'); }
window.onbeforeunload = function(){ record_visit('obul'); }
```